# ¿Como extraer el valor de una consulta y usarlo en otra consulta? (PHP y MySQL)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, variables

Que tal de nuevo tengo un problema referente a las consultas que puedo realizar a al base de datos, si bien he estructurado mi consulta y había podido usar el valor con anterioridad, ahora que quiero hacerlo de nuevo me falla, he tratado de cambiar los valores a mis variables pero no funciona, espero y me puedan ayudar.

esta es la sección del código en la que tengo el problema:

**guardar_fotoPRUEBA.php**

```
..........
$idvendor = "123456789123456789";
$nombreImagenGuardada= "codificadaaaaaaaaaa";


$obtenerlocalizacion = new CONSULTASBD();
$loc = $obtenerlocalizacion->obtenerlocalizacion($idvendor);


       foreach ($loc as $row):

   $LOCALIZACION = $row['LOCALIZACION'];
  
        endforeach;

echo $LOCALIZACION;//////// linea 40
 
 $capturacam = new CONSULTASBD();
 $res = $capturacam->capturacam($nombreImagenGuardada,$idvendor,$LOCALIZACION);///////linea 43
 .......
```

**CONSULTASBD.PHP**

```
public function obtenerlocalizacion($idvendor)
{
    $consulta = "SELECT LOCALIZACION FROM SENSORESDIS WHERE ID_SENSOR ='$idvendor'";
    //echo $consulta;
    $result = $this
        ->db
        ->query($consulta);
    $resultado = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   // echo $resultado;//// obtengo un array
        return $resultado;
    
}
```

**Resultado obtenido**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: LOCALIZACION 
in C:\directorio\guardar_fotoPRUEBA.php on line 40

Notice: Undefined variable: LOCALIZACION 
in C:\directorio\guardar_fotoPRUEBA.php on line 43
```

No sabría que pasa porque claramente tengo mis variables y especificar el valor que le quiero dar, y solo me pasa en mi variable de LOCALIZACION, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con:

```
$consulta = "SELECT LOCALIZACION FROM SENSORESDIS WHERE ID_SENSOR ='$idvendor'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$consulta);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$localizacion = $row[0];
```

Comment: Hola, igual ayuda que también describas tu solución, y cómo ese fragmento de código soluciona el problema del OP.